# What does this javascript function do? Does it make sense?

Tags: javascript

```
String.format = function()
{   var s = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++)
    {   var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
        s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
    }
  return s;
}
```

Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: looks readable to me, how about you try looking up each part in MDN.

Comment: "Does it make sense?". Well, it depends what you want to do with it. "Please explain". Explain what? What in particular do you not understand about this code?

Comment: `Please explain. Thanks.` No, you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes the first argument as a format string and replaces instances of `{0}` with the second argument, `{1}` with the third, and so on.

`String.format('{0} there, {1}', 'Hi', 'Josh');` => `Hi there, Josh`

---

Going line by line:

1. We're attaching a function named `format` to the native `String` object (note, not to *instances* of strings.  For that, you'd use `String.prototype`).
2. [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is a special object that is part of a function's *execution context* (which also includes things like the value of `this`).  It is array-like (it has keys that range from `0` to `arguments.length-1`) but it is not an Array (it is not an instance of `Array` and therefore does not have any of its prototype methods, like `pop` or `push`).  The `arguments` object is how a JavaScript function can take an arbitrary number of parameters.
3. Loop through each argument...
4. Build a regular expression which matches `{` *i* `}` where *i* is the loop iteration number.  The second argument is the regex options, `gm` enables global and multiline mode.
5. Replace matches with the supplied value
6. 
7. Return the modified string.

Answer (score 3):

It formats a string in much the same way .NET's `System.String.Format` works (if you're familiar with that); it replaces every `{someNumber}` with the `someNumber + 1`th argument. So:

```
alert(String.format('{0} + {1} = {2}', 2, 5, 7));
```

would give:

> 2 + 5 = 7

`arguments` is the "magical" array* of arguments passed to a JavaScript function.

#### Yes, it makes sense.

---

<sup>* Actually, it's not an array, but it looks like one.</sup>